# $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] is blank

Tags: php

Just found out that document_root is empty. Any alternative or idea how to fix it?

```
echo <?php $HTTP_SERVER_VARS["PATH_TRANSLATED"]  ?>
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/inc/config.php");
include(ROOT_PATH . "/inc/header.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error, your echo should be inside php tags, and add a semiclumn `;`

```
<?php echo $HTTP_SERVER_VARS["PATH_TRANSLATED"];  ?>
    //^echo should be inside php tags          ^semicolumn was missed here
```

Comment: While it's best practice to have the semi-colon, that's actually not a syntax error. It's valid if it's the only line. The echo part is definitely an error though :)

Comment: @Jes that's what i meant to say :)

Answer (score 2):

The `$_SERVER['DocumentRoot']` global depends on the server you are using, not PHP itself. If you're using Apache then just add a DocumentRoot entry to your apache configuration file:

```
DocumentRoot /absolute/path/to/website/
```

You may have an easier time just modifying your PHP to be a relative path from the current directory. Use:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/config.php';
```

Or some variation of this with the correct relative path to get from the folder of the PHP script you're editing to the config.php file, ex:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../inc/config.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use: `define('FOO_ROOT', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))`

This is useful in the case where perhaps you have index.php in the root and then you may have the code setting the root path in this way in /inc/init.php.

I don't believe their are any downsides to this technique and it's useful when perhaps you have something like cron.php (something run via a cron job) which also needs access to things in init.php. So in this context you just require inc/init.php in both of those files. I find it more DRY.